# How to get an SVG element to expand to fill the width of a container whilst preserving the aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been trying to scale an SVG to fit a container without using fixed pixel values. From what I've read online this should be possible but I haven't managed to get it to work. Some example code is shown below. Any advice on how I can get the examplesvg svg element to fill the width of the svgcontainer div (just by using HTML and CSS)? Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
background: rgb(17,17,17);
}

.svgcontainer {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
background: green;
position: relative;
}

#examplesvg {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgcontainer">
<svg><use xlink:href="#examplesvg"></use></svg>
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="examplesvg" viewBox="0 0 303 103" preserveAspectRatio="xMidyMid">
<rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /> 
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

EDIT: Updated title to make intended behaviour clearer.

Comment: I've already looked at that, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Would be interested to know why someone marked me down for this question.

Comment: You're making presumptions about how much effort I've already put into this. To make this clear, I've been struggling with this issue for the last couple of weeks, and the above question is the first question I've asked about it. I've read blog posts, read articles, watched YouTube videos about SVG and CSS positioning. As suggested before, the article you shared was one of those that I've read over the past couple of weeks. The idea behind my question was to boil down the issue to the simplest example I could think of. If you don't prefer to learn by examples perhaps you'll not see the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your CSS selector is wrong. You don't want to scale the *symbol* `#example-svg`, you want to scale the `svg` element in `.svgcontainer`. Is something like this what you were looking for?

Other things to note:

- You don't need to specify `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"`; that's equivalent to the default (see [MDN/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) for details).
- You had a typo: `preserveAspectRatio="xMidyMid"`; the y should be uppercase. SVG is *super* picky about this; you just got lucky because it's also the default. (Something you learn the hard way ;) )
- It should be `viewBox="-1.5 -1.5 303 103"`, because SVG borders get drawn half inside the shape, and half outside the shape.

```css
body { background: grey; }

.svgcontainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.svgcontainer > svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgcontainer">
  <svg><use xlink:href="#examplesvg"></use></svg>
</div>

<svg style="display:none">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="examplesvg" viewBox="-1.5 -1.5 303 103">
      <rect width="300" height="100"
        style="fill:blue;stroke-width:3;stroke:black" /> 
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: The default is `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"`. That second word can have three values: `meet` (largest size to fit inside), `slice` (smallest size to cover whole), or `none`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer cdrini, yes it appears I was targetting the wrong element. Issue is now resolved thanks to that observation. Thanks for the tips about xMidYMid also (thanks to you too, ccprog).

Comment: Thanks @ccprog ; I added a link to mdn, and changed it to say "equivalent to the default".

Answer (score 1):

@zenoArrow, please check the below working snippet for the resolved issue you were facing.

let me explain, what went wrong:

1. set `width` and `height` to the svg within the div `svgcontainer`. so that it scale fully, if not mentioned it will set the `viewBox="0 0 300 100"` width and height to the svg
2. don't use `preserveAspectRatio="xMidyMid"` instead use `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to scale/fill the svg as per the parent container, if not added it will scale horizontaly but not vertically.
3. `viewBox="0 0 303 103"` should be equal to `<rect width="300" height="100"`, it also depends on your requirement though.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(17, 17, 17);
}

.svgcontainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.example-svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="examplesvg" viewBox="0 0 300 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="svgcontainer">
  <svg class="example-svg">
    <use xlink:href="#examplesvg"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Girish, but regarding "don't use preserveAspectRatio="xMidyMid" instead use preserveAspectRatio="none" to scale/fill the svg as per the parent container, if not added it will scale horizontaly but not vertically." that's not the behaviour I'm looking for. I'm only looking to fill the horizontal width, not the vertical width. The code I shared is a simplified example to get the point across, but ultimately the SVG I'll be using is a logo for a website. Aside from that, I'll take a look through your code to see if I can get the behaviour I was looking for.

Comment: ok, then ignore that `preserveAspectRatio` part,
if my answer is fine, can accept it :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help Girish. I upvoted your answer as I appreciated your assistance.